# Linking two independent clauses

Tags: clauses

Is there any way to link these two clauses? (I overthought it, so my brain suddenly went blank)

(in these examples: Amy is a child going on a trip, accompanied by two families of friends who are also going on the trip)

> Two other families were also going on this trip. The parents agreed to look after Amy.

Can you link them like this, using 'in which'?

> Two other families were also going on this trip, in which the parents agreed to look after Amy.

How about another structure?

> On this trip, the other travelling families' parents agreed to look after Amy.

Do any of these make sense? Does the third one do a bad job of introducing? If yes, how can I improve it? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Who is Amy? Is Amy going on the trip? Is Amy a child or a parent, or both? Are Amy's parents and or children going on the trip? What is the relationship of Amy to the two other families?

Comment: By the way, it's usually best to wait 24 hours before accepting an answer, even if you get a good one right away. More info is [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you actually want to say, you can ***[connect](https://www.sbcc.edu/clrc/files/wl/downloads/IndependentandDependentClauses.pdf)*** the two independent clauses in any number of ways.

As you suggested works adequately, making the second a *[relative clause](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/relative-clauses/)* :

> *Two other families were also going on this trip, in which the parents agreed to look after Amy.*

Making a time connection with *while* makes the second a [*dependent clause*](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/dependent_clause.htm):

> *Two other families were also going on this trip, while the parents agreed to look after Amy.*

You could choose any other *subordinating conjunction* from the list of common ones below to fit your meaning:

> after, 
>   *although*, 
>   **as**,  as if, 
>   *as long as*, 
>   **as though**,  because, 
>   *before*, 
>   **even if**,  even though, 
>   *if*, 
>   **if only**,  in order that, 
>   *now that*, 
>   **once**,  rather than, 
>   *since*, 
>   **so that**,  than, 
>   *that*, 
>   **though**,  till, 
>   *unless*, 
>   **until**,  when, 
>   *whenever*, 
>   **where**,  whereas, 
>   *wherever*, 
>   **while**,

A simple **coordination** with *and*:

> *Two other families were also going on this trip, and the parents agreed to look after Amy.*

or *but* (or any other *[FANBOYS](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/8-3punc.html)*):

> *Two other families were also going on this trip, but the parents agreed to look after Amy.*

You could use a semi-colon:

> *Two other families were also going on this trip; the parents agreed to look after Amy.*

or a semi-colon with *in fact*:

> *Two other families were also going on this trip; in fact, the parents agreed to look after Amy.*

And if that is not enough, you can also make the first clause dependent on, or relative to, the second.

Talk about flexibility!